# Improving a Web Login Screen

Tags: user-interface, authentication

I'm trying to get some ideas about how to develop a web login screen. I'm using DynamicData Webforms, so most of powerful frameworks offers a lot of options, but I'll be very grateful to read your suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Edited:
beyond the functionality, I'll want to read your view-point about the presentation model, i said, im using fx3.5 so improve more than 2 textbox for a single login or using the login aspx control, i have in mind use silverlight but is possible to "light my webapp" that is build in webforms and dynamicdata with out change all the presentation layer?

More Undestandable: Example of using Extjs as Presentation Framework for View Layer, but my project is webforms so this will be nice for MVC.net i said cause is more flexible in json concerns

[alt text http://rodotelmi.rebstech.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/picture-1.png](http://rodotelmi.rebstech.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/picture-1.png)

Comment: Is the site going to be open to public

Comment: What do you want to improve? the gui? I do not get your edit...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please have a look at 65+ examples of login screen for some inspiration...

[65+ Login form design](http://www.smileycat.com/design_elements/login_forms/)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it depends on your application.  If you are developing a public web site where you want to drive up the number of registered users and increase the click count on your publicly available pages, then a full-featured* login or a convenient login control on each page makes sense.  If it is an intranet application where login is required to access anything, then a simple login page with minimal information is appropriate.  You also need to decide if login is persistent across browser sessions or not and whether you want to give the user a choice, that will determine whether you need a "remember me" button or not.  You also want to provide links to contact information and basic help (or a means to recover a lost id/password) if appropriate.

- by full-featured I mean something similar to @Danny's suggestion that other parts of the application be easily accessible from the login page.

Answer (score 1):

I do not like when website have only 1 field than you need to press a button, than it's a field for the password : In two steps.

**Keep it simple and minimalism**. I suggest you to have your login screen in all windows when the user is not login and not have him to go on a login page.

Comment: Err, what?  Not really understandably worded advice.

Answer (score 0):

- Have 2 textboxes : email (or username) and password.
- A button to submit.
- A link for "Forget your password".
- A checkbox to "remember me".

Answer (score 0):

The trick to a good login screen is to make it as interesting as the rest of your application, and give users useful links and other information there, as well as within your app (anything that doesn't require credentials, of course).

Take a look at the Facebook login page for a good example. In addition to the normal login infrastructure, you can search for users from there, sign up for the site, see their policies, etc.

Comment: i know im using facebook, but I am not convinced at all about presentation (login),

Answer (score 0):

the trick is make it as minimal as possible learn from google UI

This book is great book for UI design does not take your much of time to read [Dont make me think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758)

Answer (score 0):

Keep it as simple and friendly as possible. It is important to make it the key focus if it on it's own screen so minimise the page to only show what you need, otherwise make it prominent in the header or sidebar.

For design and layout inspiration check out [Pattern Tap](http://patterntap.com/tap/collection/login) or [box.mepholio](http://box.mepholio.com/collections/13/recent).

For the best user experience and form completion time, top aligned labels and a left-aligned submit button are good way to go if you have enough vertical space eg http://www.sanchothefat.com/projects/forms/login.

Answer (score 0):

This resource can be useful too.
http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/interface-design-loginsignup